# Unresolved External - DirectX11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, directx

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Setup, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Effects11d.lib(EffectAPI.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DCompileFromFile@36 referenced in function _D3DX11CompileEffectFromFile
1>C:\Users\Josh\Documents\Game Institute\DirectX\Chapter 1\Projects\Setup\Debug\Setup.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've been trying to setup **DirectX11 with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7**, following Frank Lunas instructions in his DirectX11 book for awhile now and I keep running into errors.

Currently this is my error, I have 'D3DCompiler.lib' and i've updated the Effects Library, here is a picture of the debug mode properties:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jb64vc&s=5

Release mode properties are the same but with the 'd' removed on two library files. 'Effects11d' for example.

Please help me! It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Add: $(DXSDK_DIR)include to include directories and $(DXSDK_DIR)lib\x86 to library directories, let me know what it says after that

Comment: @FlorisVelleman They are already added, if you look at the picture you can see that.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302276/d3dcompiler-unresolved-extern

Comment: @FlorisVelleman I've tried that, and it's not working either. I'm really at a loss, any more ideas?

Comment: I would suggest moving away from the effects library. 1 is deprecated. 2 It's actually not that hard to compile and set your own shaders. 3. You need better performance when setting constant buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the legacy DirectX SDK for this unless you are also using D3DX11 (which you also don't really need as there are [replacements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx)). The latest Effects 11 that doesn't require the legacy DirectX SDK is available on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271568).

Remember that you are expected to build Effects 11 from source. There's no 'Effects11.lib' or "Effects11D.lib" shipped in the DirectX SDK or elsewhere. You add the vcxproj to your solution, and then add a 'Reference' to your main project to link to it.